# How do I organize all the rows that contain the same FK ID into one row that shows all the items inside those rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make all the data I have in my database organized by SaleID, this is how I have my DB right now. SalesID and ProductID are foreign keys.

TID.......SaleID .........ProductID
....1...............1.......................1
....2...............1.......................4
....3...............1.......................6
....4...............2.......................3
....5...............3.......................1
....6...............3.......................5
....7...............4.......................3
....8...............5.......................3
....9...............5.......................6

I want to make a table that shows all the data organized like this. Not stored into a database just to output this information.

SaleID........Products
.........1.......1,4,6
.........2.......3
.........3.......1,5
.........4.......3
.........5.......3,6

I was trying to do this with multidimensional arrays but every iteration it added a new row and showed exactly the same thing as the first table not being able to modify or add to a past row.

this is the code that I have right now

```
<?php 
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('mydb');


$query="SELECT * FROM prodsales ORDER by salesID ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table border='1'>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['salesID'] . "</td><td>" . $row['productID'] . "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysql_close();



?>
```

Comment: check `group_concat` function in mysql

Comment: You've tagged this with PHP, so don't GROUP_CONCAT the data, just process it in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SaleID , GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT ProductID SEPARATOR ',' ) AS PID FROM prodsales GROUP BY SaleID
```

Please try this hope it help you to get what you wnat

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a lovely  group_concat function as Abhik posted in a comment. You can use it like this to get the distinct rows you want and to make the other matching rows a comma (or just about anything else) separated list:

```
select
    saleID,
    group_concat(productID)
from
    prodsales
group by
    saleID
order by
    saleID
```

This will return the rows in the format you want and you can simply then output into the table as you are doing.